# Ctrl+K was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate` and when I select a code to be comment I press Ctrl+K but it show me this once I pressed `Ctrl+K was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...` any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It's Ctrl K + Ctrl C to comment a block.

Comment: And Ctrl K + Ctrl U to uncomment

Comment: @sab669 May want to direct the OP how to check keyboard bindings, on my machine its Ctrl-E + Ctrl-C

Comment: yes, I mean Ctrl K it's not work with me it show me this Ctrl+K was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord... , before it's work with me Ctrl K and Ctrl U now not work

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks Ron; I was looking at my 2010 install. 2013 is Ctrl E + Ctrl C for me too. That's weird, why would they decide to change that :(

Comment: Also, @sarahkhaled You might want to tag this question with just the IDE you're using-- C#, .NET and ASP aren't *really* relevant here. The shortcuts are the same no matter what language or platform you're working on, it's tied to VS itself.

Comment: none of the chosen tags are relevant to the question

Comment: @sab669 sorry about that I change it now to visual studio 2013

Comment: @kai thank you to mention me, I change it now to visual studio 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command Ctrl K+C to comment any line, and Ctrl K+U to uncomment.

Answer (score 2):

You can look after and manage your shortcuts in Tools / Options, Environment / Keyboard.
You should see a dropdown menu where all shortcuts are listed.
There you can change your existing shortcuts or reset them to the default.
The default shortcut for me (Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition) to comment was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and to uncomment <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can see what the keyboard binding is under Edit > Advanced > Comment Selection (2010):

[image]

And 2013:

[image]

Additionally, you find keyboard bindings under `Tools` > `Options` > `Environment` > `Keyboard`. Here if you search for "Comment", you can find the `Edit.CommentSelection` (and `Edit.UncommentSelection`) which you can assign whichever shortcut you prefer.

Comment: thank you very much for this solution, it's work but it's hard now every time I go to Advance then comment, I want like before press Ctrl K it make easy to do comments

Comment: I edited in some instructions at the bottom of the post on how to find and change keyboard shortcuts. I believe you should be able to assign just `Ctrl K`; I agree that having to use multiple key combinations or the tool menus to be awkward for such a useful feature.